# Equation label is wrong

Tags: equations, labels

I am currently trying to cite an equation array, but it is citing me the next equation, weirdly (see figure). Can anyone help me?

I am using the following code:

```
Considering a logarithmic transformation, the P-wave signal $p[n]$ and its Gaussian model $\hat{p}[n]$ were related as:
\begin{eqnarray}
ln(p[n])&=&ln(\hat{p}[n]) 
\\\nonumber &=&ln(A) - \bigg(\frac{n-C}{W}\bigg)^2 \label{eq:log_gauss}
\end{eqnarray}
Defining the variables $b=ln(p[n])$, $a_2=-1/W^2$, $a_1=2C/W^2$, and $a_0=ln(A)-(C/W)^2$, Equation \ref{eq:log_gauss} can be written as a second-order polynomial:
\begin{eqnarray}
b&=&-\frac{1}{W^2}n^2+\frac{2C}{W^2}n+ln(A)-\bigg(\frac{C}{W}\bigg)^2
\\\nonumber &=&a_2n^2+a_1n+a_0
\end{eqnarray}
Considering discrete values of $n$, coefficients $a_2$, $a_1$, and $a_0$ can be obtained by solving the following system of linear equation:
```

[image]

Comment: Please move the `\nonumber` before `\\ `. And use `\ln` instead of `ln`.

Comment: It worked! Why tho? Btw, post this as answer, so that I can mark it as correct

Comment: The reason is that you tell latex not to put a number at a line of an equation that you want to label. So, in a way, this label is "lost" and cannot be referenced (correctly). (Personally I prefer to put the number at the last line of the equation, and that's why I suggested to move `\nonumber` up. I also would refrain from using `:` but these are of course just opinions.)

Comment: Hehe, you just hit one of my examples in the tugboat article I wrote about why you should ever ever use `eqnarray`, it steps up the equation counter at the start of a row, and steps it down at the end if `\nonumber` is used. But in between `\label` can easily pickup equation data, see tugboat 33-1 2012, http://tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/contents33-1.html

Comment: @daleif I am not going to write an answer, so please feel free to do so. (It would be great if you could add to this answer how to increase the space around the equality signs a bit. I know that the spacing in eqnarray has often been dubbed "excessive" but perhaps not by those who really have to read papers and try to access the information contained in the equations very efficiently. I'd love to know a trick which just adds some space around `=` signs in display mode, not as much as in `eqnarray`.)

Comment: @marmot the issue is consistency, the spacing around = should be the same throughout the entire document, it should not be larger in displays. Most people using eqnarray does so because they do not know better, noone told them it was bad. (and then there are those who are just either lazy or does not care about concistency or readability)

Comment: @daleif Well, it is your opinion that equality signs should always have the same spacing. Others may feel integral signs should look always the same, and the limits should always be treated the same way. I disagree with these opinions. Displaystyle should IMHO look different, after all before and after an `equation` there is space, precisely to make it easier to spot the equation. And for readability I would prefer to have larger spaces around the equality signs, simply because I want to be able to absorb the equation very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

The placement of `\nonumber` is wrong.

However, you should *never* use `eqnarray`. Besides producing wrong space around the equals signs, it ***doesn't*** cooperate with `hyperref`.

I suggest using `split`, since you're referring to the whole equations and not just to one line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Considering a logarithmic transformation, the $P$\nobreakdash-wave signal 
$p[n]$ and its Gaussian model $\hat{p}[n]$ were related as
\begin{equation} \label{eq:log_gauss}
\begin{split}
\ln(p[n])
&=\ln(\hat{p}[n]) 
\\
&=\ln(A) - \biggl(\frac{n-C}{W}\biggr)^{\!2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Defining the variables $b=\ln(p[n])$, $a_2=-1/W^2$, $a_1=2C/W^2$, 
and $a_0=\ln(A)-(C/W)^2$, Equation \ref{eq:log_gauss} can be written as 
a second-order polynomial
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
b&=
-\frac{1}{W^2}n^2+\frac{2C}{W^2}n+\ln(A)-\biggl(\frac{C}{W}\biggr)^{\!2}
\\
&=a_2n^2+a_1n+a_0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Considering discrete values of $n$, coefficients $a_2$, $a_1$, and $a_0$ 
can be obtained by solving the following system of linear equations

\end{document}
```

Note `\ln` instead of `ln`. Also `\biggl(` and `\biggr)` should be used, not the unadorned `\bigg` in either case.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As @marmot correctly said, I do not want to take his credit, you have to shift the `\nonumber` command before the `\\` and use the `\ln` command for the logarithm instead of just writing ln.

I write this answer so that someone, like me, who encounters the same (or a similar one) problem knows that it has been solved.